# :hover only works when forced in Inspector

Tags: html, css

On my homepage, the `top_fixed_right:hover` element works perfectly.

On a secondary page however, the same `div` only works when forcing the `:hover` state with the developer tools window in Chrome. It doesn't work when hovering the mouse over the `div`.

I opened the same page in Safari with no luck (homepage: yes, secondary page: no)

```css
.top_fixed_right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15;
  top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
  transition: right 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.top_fixed_right:hover {
  right: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_fixed_right">
  <p>About me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: change `right: 15` as   `right: 15px;`

Comment: Add `px` to your CSS right property. `right: 15px;` and `right: 10px;`

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify `px` after the value in pixels. It works for me now.

```css
.top_fixed_right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
  transition: right 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.top_fixed_right:hover {
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_fixed_right">
  <p>About me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In css `right` property expects a pixel value and you were only setting `10` and `15` to it.

These values needs to be in pixel, change:

```
.top_fixed_right:hover {
  right: 10;
}
```

To:

```
.top_fixed_right:hover {
  right: 10px;
}
```

This is your snippet updated:

```css
.top_fixed_right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
  transition: right 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.top_fixed_right:hover {
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_fixed_right">
  <p>About me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
.top_fixed_right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
  transition: right 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_fixed_right">
  <p>About me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using px after every value you assign to different attributes, though some advance browsers will do it for you but you should be more accurate being a coder. If you add 'px' where you are assigning value to attribute right in hover event.

```
right: 15;  <!-- Not a good practice-->

right: 15px; <!-- Correct syntax-->
```

You have set the position to fixed so :hover event is not able to move that text so change the position attribute or it is even better if you use onmouseover and onmouseout attributes, because these has priority higher than css.

Check the below code, I hope it helps.

```css
.top_fixed_right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s;
  transition: right 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_fixed_right" onmouseover="this.style.right='10px'" onmouseout="this.style.right='15px'">
  <p>About me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it's my first coding project hence the rookie mistakes. It did however not solve my problem with the transition on the secondary page, it only works on the homepage.

Comment: add the complete code and then explain your problem clearly so community can help you out